# Reorder a subset of an R data.frame modifying the row names as well

Tags: r, dataframe

Given a data.frame:

```
foo <- data.frame(ID=1:10, x=1:10)
rownames(foo) <- LETTERS[1:10]
```

I would like to reorder a subset of rows, defined by their row names. However, I would like to swap the row names of foo as well. I can do

```
sel <- c("D", "H") # rows to reorder
foo[sel,] <- foo[rev(sel),]
sel.wh <- match(sel, rownames(foo))
rownames(foo)[sel.wh] <- rownames(foo)[rev(sel.wh)]
```

but that is long and complicated. Is there a simpler way?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We can replace the `sel` values in `rownames` with the reverse of `sel`.

```
x <- rownames(foo)
foo[replace(x, x %in% sel, rev(sel)), ]

#  ID  x
#A  1  1
#B  2  2
#C  3  3
#H  8  8
#E  5  5
#F  6  6
#G  7  7
#D  4  4
#I  9  9
#J 10 10
```

Comment: Lovely! Thank you very much. This is EXACTLY what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

Not as concise as ronak-shah's answer, but you could also use `order`.

```
# extract row names
temp <- row.names(foo)
# reset of vector
temp[which(temp %in% sel)] <- temp[rev(which(temp %in% sel))]
# reset order of data.frame
foo[order(temp),]
  ID  x
A  1  1
B  2  2
C  3  3
H  8  8
E  5  5
F  6  6
G  7  7
D  4  4
I  9  9
J 10 10
```

---

As noted in the comments, this relies on the row names following a lexicographical order. In instances where this is not true, we can use `match`.

```
# set up
set.seed(1234)
foo <- data.frame(ID=1:10, x=1:10)
row.names(foo) <- sample(LETTERS[1:10])
sel <- c("D", "H")
```

Now, the rownames are

```
# initial data.frame
foo
  ID  x
B  1  1
F  2  2
E  3  3
H  4  4
I  5  5
D  6  6
A  7  7
G  8  8
J  9  9
C 10 10

# grab row names
temp <- row.names(foo)

# reorder vector containing row names
temp[which(temp %in% sel)] <- temp[rev(which(temp %in% sel))]
```

Using, `match` along with order

```
foo[order(match(row.names(foo), temp)),]
  ID  x
B  1  1
F  2  2
E  3  3
D  6  6
I  5  5
H  4  4
A  7  7
G  8  8
J  9  9
C 10 10
```

Comment: Elegant, but it works under the assumption that the row names are alphabetical. My fault -- I used LETTERS[1:10] just to make a simple example. sample(LETTERS[1:10], 10) would have been a much better idea.

Answer (score 0):

your data frame is small so you can duplicate it then change the value of each raw:

```
footmp<-data.frame(foo)
foo[4,]<-footemp[8,]
foot{8,]<-footemp[4,]
```

Bob

Comment: Your code hase multiple typos and I don't think that  OP's real data is as small as this example. More importantly, it does not change the row names as required